# How to save webpage in Qt WebKit as "save as complete webpage"

Tags: javascript, qt, dom, webkit, qtwebkit

I need to save web page using Qt WebKit similar to *"Save as complete webpage"*.

Following are my requirements,

1. Save the index html file, maintaining entity encoding.
2. Need to download all linked images and other resources.
3. Need to change resource path in html page  to local downloaded path.
4. Need to maintain webpage current state.

I can use Qt and JavaScript to do this.

Please provide me some inputs on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML parser to parse the current page, then look for all the images (xpath "//img"), download their files, and change their src attributes.

Answer (score 0):

how about save the html to local system and call setHtml() when you need it?